# What is the difference between "BETWEEN AND" and "> AND <=" on datetime?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, query-optimization

Each on our team has their own method on extracting data between dates and we've come with two common methods of extracting data using:

1. [DateTimeColumn]BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
2. [DateTimeColumn] > @StartDate AND[DateTimeColumn] <= @EndDate

When to use/Difference "BETWEEN" and "> AND  <=" on datetime : SQL Query Optimization and which of the two is the best to use.

Comment: Normally, if you're not using BETWEEN/AND, you would use `value >= start AND value < end` (the opposite convention from the one you use).  One reason for that is that if you insert a value at time T1, then selecting `value >= T1 AND value < T2 + x` will pick up the row inserted at T1.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`BETWEEN`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187922.aspx) operator uses *inclusive* ends of the interval. Use specific compare operations whenever you are looking to exclude one or both ends of the interval.

Additionally, `BETWEEN` is convenient when you test against a complex expression: for example, writing something like

```
... AND CASE WHEN A>0 THEN open_date ELSE close_date END BETWEEN '01/01/2012' AND '05/01/2012'
```

is easier than repeating the `CASE` expression twice.

Answer (score 1):

Just adding to the point made by dashblinkenlight , I actually don't see any performance issue with Between and <> operator . You can check the query plan in both the situation .The only obvious difference is Between is inclusive.